# Google Cal - How to get completed/past events

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I use the code below to fetch the user's `calendar` events for the current day.

TODAY_MS is a `timestamp` of the start of the day and ONE_DAY_MS is a day in `milliseconds (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)`.

However, this code only gets upcoming events. It doesn't return earlier events in the day.

(i.e.: If I run this at 3PM, it won't return an event that happened from 1 to 2 PM because the event is completed.)

How would I go about getting all of the events in a time period, including those who are completed?

```
Uri.Builder builder = WearableCalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(builder, TODAY_MS);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, TODAY_MS + ONE_DAY_MS - 1);
final Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(builder.build(), null, null, null, null); // Could optimize this line for speed.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In [`Google Calendar API v3`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#request), under [`Events:list`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#request), you can use the parameter `timeMin` and `timeMax` for an event's time to filter.

Here's an sample of minimum and maximum time:

```
timeMin='2012-10-25T00:00:00Z' 
timeMax='2012-10-26T00:00:00Z'
```

You may also get 2 different date like this:

```
// Start date from where to get the events
$query->setStartMin('2013-01-01');
// End date
$query->setStartMax('2013-03-20');
```